# how to make a site mobile responsive when data is being pulled from another server

Tags: css, wordpress, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I have created [this website](http://www.bassgroupre.com) for a real estate client but am having a lot of trouble making the `idx` feed that is being pulled in responsive.

I am using a responsive theme (`u-design`) and it is working on mobile sites but the `idx` feeds that are located on the site are not.  I know that I will have to edit some `css` files and such...

That is fine with me but I just don't know how to do it.  I've spent a few days trying to compare files with other sites to see if I could figure it out but I just can't.  It is all very overwhelming to me.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: No one wants to reverse-engineer an external site. Please read the FAQ on how to properly ask questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: As overwhelming as such things can be, you are best off finding a thorough reference manual and spending a day absorbing...

Comment: yes, i now realize that i didn't ask my question correctly and i apologize... 
in all honesty, after trying to find a similar problem, i didn't even know how to ask the question i needed answered.  but Ennui has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be possible if the IDX feed is just code served from another server, which in my experience it usually is (via an iframe).

If you don't have any way to access or change that server-side code you won't be able to do much, and if it's in an iframe the difference in source protocol between the frame and your website will prevent you from using client-side responsive techniques to make the IDX output responsive.  If the IDX feed is piped in via iframe and its content isn't already responsive there isn't much you can do without having access to the code that generates the IDX feed itself.

Comment: it's not an iframe. i've had to make a subdomain that only the idx uses and there is a "global wrapper" (page curling) that makes the results look like the rest of the site.  i have access to edit the css for the idx results but like i said.... it's all just overwhelming, especially when i'm not 100% sure what i am supposed to be changing.  as diodeus mentioned above, "No one wants to reverse-engineer an external site" and i totally understand.  i was just hoping there might be an easy answer :(

Comment: In that case it should be possible (make your wrapper code responsive on your end, and apply responsive CSS to the IDX content on their end).  There is no "easy" solution though, you have to go in and modify all of the CSS to make it responsive.  For a hacky kind of situation like this where you don't have control over the markup I would say the easiest way to go about it is to just write a bunch of hacky CSS media queries until it looks decent on all screen widths.

Comment: Look up @media css queries on google. simplest way to implement them is just using progressively smaller `@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) { //code }` queries to define CSS presets for different screen widths.  Often in situations like this a combination of static pixel widths and percentages is easier than the trouble of trying to force disorganized markup into being a fully fluid responsive site.  Sadly there is no way around having to do the grunt work here - just take a day and read up on media queries, it might seem intimidating but it's very doable.

Comment: thank you SO much for taking the time to respond!  since the wrapper code is already responsive (i'm assuming it is already responsive since everything that shows up on the page that isn't related with idx  (header, footers, text) still responds to mobile) i will have to add the media queries to code on the idx website, correct?

Comment: Yeah - probably the easiest way to do it is save a static HTML version of the page WITH the IDX code rendered on it, then write a custom stylesheet with media queries that target the non-responsive elements of the code output by the IDX provider.  That way you can test offline without having to upload your CSS to the IDX software every time you want to see it (media queries tend to be one of those things you switch between the editor and browser A LOT to tweak little values).  If this helps please upvote/mark this question as the answer (the check box)!